# Значение слова «вобчью»

Tags: значение-слов, выбор-слов, литература

Привожу цитату из «Сродства мировых сил» Козьмы Пруткова:

Свет земле вобчью.
Вывожу зарю.
Что свершилось ночью —
Вскоре озарю.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что такое «вобчью»? Буду признательна.

Comment: "Вобчью" -- это "воочью", написанное с ошибкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ольга:

> Привожу цитату из «Сродства мировых сил» Козьмы Пруткова:
>
> Свет земле вобчью.
>
> Вывожу зарю.
>
> Что свершилось ночью —
>
> Вскоре озарю.
>
> Подскажите, пожалуйста, что такое «вобчью»?

Мимоходов правильно написал в своём ответе: ошибка оцифровки.  У Козьмы Пруткова ни в одном из просмотренных мною бумажных изданиях "вобчью" нет. Есть: ***воо́чью***.

Вот как этот отрывок выглядел, к примеру, в 7-ом издании полного собрания сочинений Козьмы Пруткова, вышедшем в 1899 году:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А употребляться это слово во времена Козьмы Пруткова могло не только в значениях, к которым мы привыкли...

Answer (score 3):

Это просто опечатка. Правильный текст такой:

**ЯВЛЕНИЕ VIII**

После долгой ночи небосклон начинает наконец алеть на востоке.

**Солнце за горизонтом**

*Свет земле **воочью.**

Вывожу зарю.

Что свершилось ночью —

Вскоре озарю.*

[**СРОДСТВО МИРОВЫХ СИЛ. Мистерия в одиннадцати явлениях**](http://www.kozma.ru/works/dramas/affinity.htm)
[**Прутков Козьма — Сочинения**](http://nemaloknig.info/read-160604/?page=33#booktxt) (дополнение 2)
[**Сочинения Козьмы Пруткова**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=ZNprCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA302&lpg=PA302&dq=%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%8C%D1%8E.%20%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%83%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8E.%20%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%8C%D1%8E%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%92%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8E.&source=bl&ots=ZEDvdpmdnQ&sig=n8Apexqbu9w5CTWmEPmOn5ZXiiA&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifyN6s7__UAhVCYpoKHZ4-B_MQ6AEIKTAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%8C%D1%8E.%20%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D1%83%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8E.%20%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%8C%D1%8E%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%92%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8E.&f=false) (дополнение 3)

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 1**

Есть такой ("странно-неверный") источник:

ЯВЛЕНИЕ VIII
После долгой ночи небосклон начинает наконец алеть на востоке.

```
 Солнце за горизонтом
 Свет земле вобчью.(?)
 Вывожу зарю.
 Что свершилось ночью -
 Вскоре озарю.
```

[**Козьма Прутков. Сродство мировых сил**](http://www.theatre-library.ru/files/p/prutkov/prutkov_2.html)

Comment: *Есть такой ("странно-неверный") источник:*  там же ясно сказано: **OCR Pirat, доп. правка В. Есаулов, март -апрель 2005 г.** Вот к г-ну Pirat'у и претензии.

Answer (score 2):

Результат оперативно-разыскной деятельности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из трёх неполных цитат на скрине, разночтений... не одно. Точка или точка с запятой после "вобчью"? Есть ли тире после "ночью"? И даже одна "зоря" фигурирует.

Тогда идём в С.-Петербург, в 1894 год:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полное собрание предполагает-таки тщательную корректуру, однако загадка (которая и породила дальнейшие недоразумения) - зачем в слове "воочью" проставлять ударение?

А вот то, что в позднейших переизданиях пропало ударение у "что" - это уже брак.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полный текстъ мистеріи въ одиннадцати явленіяхъ **[читать здѣсь](http://imwerden.de/pdf/kozma_prutkov_polnoe_sobranie_sochineny_1894__ocr.pdf)**.

---

Дополнение для верующих в хвосты - смотрим на букву ***б*** в других местах этого  же издания (шрифт - один):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем в слове "воочью" проставлять ударение? Так это и не знак ударения, а хвост буквы. Знак — двумя строчками ниже — штрих справа-вниз-налево. Спасибо.

Comment: "Небосклон" в длинной, с лишними запятыми строке тоже с хвостом? Надо было открыть доступный текст и сравнить (добавляю в ответ).

Answer (score 1):

**Воочью.**
Ошибка оцифровки скорее всего. 
Опечаткой я бы такие вещи не называл.
А источник ваш не покажете? Вообще в таких случаях надо сверяться по академическим изданиям, лучше - бумажным или проверенным.

Ссылку на выверенный текст вам уже дали. Хотя там тоже - без гарантии, но это все-таки куда более надежный источник, чем оцифровка.

Answer (score -1):

В Словаре ЦСРЯ есть такое слово.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предположу, что «Свет земле вобчью» — позволяющее видеть только общие очертания местности и предметов свечение небес. Оно диффузно, и ещё нельзя определить то место, где покажется солнце.

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо! :)